# trouble while using anaconda2 and pycharm

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

after i installed anaconda2, and my interpreter is the python.exe in anaconda2. But there is no package like numpy, scipy, matplotlib .etc in the environment.

[image: it's my project interpreter setting]

[image: it's environment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install additional packages like numpy and scipy via pip command, for example:

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think these packages should be included in anaconda. My trouble is why my anaconda doesn't include these packages

Comment: Perhaps it is due to virtual environment

Comment: thanks for helping!   it works after I change virtual environment to system environment